# Add Custom CSS Section to Shopify Theme

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, assets

I want to be able to add a custom CSS class to, in this case, a Slider section.

In my `slider-vertical.liquid` asset, I went down to the `{% schema %}` and under `settings` I added this code:

```
{
"type": "text",
    "id": "section_css_class",
    "label": {
      "en": "Section CSS Class"
    },
    "default": {
      "en": "Add CSS class"
    }
  }
,
```

Then, at the top of the same file, I modified the DIV wrapper from this:

```
<div class="vertical-slider {% if text_brightness < 60 %} has-black-text {% endif %}">
```

to this:

```
<div class="vertical-slider {% if text_brightness < 60 %} has-black-text {% endif %} {{ section.settings.section_css_class }}">
```

The CSS Class name I type in the "Add CSS class" box which I now see at my Theme Editor does not appear to be read. I tried many tests and I see that there must be something wrong under `schema` because it's not populating the text I add.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

default is not a label, it is a value for the field.
checkout [default](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/sections/section-schema#default) here

`<div class="vertical-slider {% if text_brightness < 60 %} has-black-text {% endif %} {{ section.settings.section_css_class }}">`

will be

`<div class="vertical-slider {% if text_brightness < 60 %} has-black-text {% endif %} Add CSS class ">`

in

```
{
"type": "text",
    "id": "section_css_class",
    "label": {
      "en": "Section CSS Class"
    },
    "default": "Add CSS class"
    }
  }
,
```

Just change `default` to `"default": "my-css-class"` and it should work

to debug, just output the value of `section.settings.section_css_class` with a `div` like this

```
<div>
    {{section.settings.section_css_class}}
</div>
```